# My Asus ROG IX Code motherboard does not turn on

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, power-supply, desktop-computer

Recently I've bought an **ASUS Republic of Gamers (ROG) Maximus IX Code motherboard** and after connection all of the needed modules including CPU, RAM, GPU, Fans, etc I recognized that my computer does not turn on.

Actually when I switch the power on, the LED lights start to flash and as I know this means that the motherboard gets the power but when I plugin the front panel power button's connectors to the motherboard the power button does not function.

I also tried to boot my computer without using a power button and what I did was: **using a screw driver to connect the two power pins on the mother board to make the system turn on manually** but it didn't work either.

**Finally I tried updating the BIOS**, for that I downloaded the latest version of the bios and after extracting it I renamed it to M9F.CAP as mentioned in the motherboard's user guide and copied that file to the root of a USB flash drive. Then I connected the flash drive to the related input for BIOS and I pressed the Clear CMOS button then I pressed and held BIOS button for 3 seconds, so it started to flash and after three flashes it remained on and didn't go out.(as mentioned in the user guide) Can it cause damage to BISO Software? If yes, how can I fix it?

All in all, the system does not boot up after all these steps, does anyone have any idea? please help me fix this issue because I cannot reach an ASUS Service center in my city.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Yes of course, here you are:
[link](http://uupload.ir/view/zcns_4.jpg)
[link](http://uupload.ir/view/q4rx_1.jpg)
[link](http://uupload.ir/view/qwkf_2.jpg)
[link](http://uupload.ir/view/fj38_3.jpg)
[link](http://uupload.ir/view/pu41_5.jpg)

Comment: I think I missed the BIOS flash part but I would not have done that at all since you just built this it's likely something else. It sounds like you were able to get power to the MOBO and hear the CPU fan running and any lights on GPU card and GPU card fan running but no video, correct? Or are you saying you cannot figure out how to get MOBO powered ON via the power button pins? Are you sure or unsure you were able to get power to the mobo?

Comment: To ensure you are not overlooking anything simple, did you try this [start button](https://i.imgur.com/Mo4Rih0.png) which is this [start button](https://i.imgur.com/bYFxdHG.png) as referenced in the mobo manufacturer User's Manual? Help me understand a little better that what you wrote in the question and in addition to the pics which is all good info by the way, just need to  keep adding to troubleshoot.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT thanks for your suggestions, I did them all, but it still does not work, I believe that this issue can be because of the BIOS update and for more information I have to say that on these motherboards you can update the bios without OS all you need is a power supply then you should download and copy the update file to the root of a usb and try updating the device using that. The user guide says that when you press the update BIOS button it should flash a few times and when it turns off it means that the process is done but mine remains on.

Comment: Have you tried all GPU slots and what video output is your monitor connecting like the built-in DisplayPort, HDMI, or something on the GPU? Have you tried all fittable PCIe slots one by one on the MOBO for the GPU and video. Does GPU fan turn on, does CPU fan turn on, does the PSU fan turn on ... any of those ever? You get not output of video or see any lights or fans turn on or anything??

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT My problem is that only the lights of the motherboard are turned on after connecting the Power supply and none of my fans or other modules work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, I found out that my motherboard does not support Intel Core i7 8700K Coffee Lake CPU and I have to change it to Asus ROG Maximums X Code.